# Subreport list not displaying all values

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have one main abc.jrxml that contain pqr.jrxml. I am passing list from abc to pqr. Some values are getting displayed but some values are not getting displayed. I have tried some properties to apply subreport but it didn't worked.

How can I stretch subreport dynamically?

Comment: u can display like this :D LOL, what is written in jrxml isn't here. how will other help you ?

Comment: Yeah ! but this code I cant share. Thats why I am asking is there any property to dynamically stretch the subreport?

Comment: obviously it has. just read jasper report documentation

Comment: I used overflowType="Stretch". but still some properties are missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - can create an example showing code that helps illustrate the problem. (Horizontal stretching is typically accomplished using [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/).)